# Computation of Betti numbers of a given space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Trying to verify my computations below. I don't have much intuition for homology or the Betti numbers computation. It's a simple case, yet somehow intuitively I'm surprised to get $\beta_1(W) = 3$.

Is my computation wrong?

---

---

Here is how I construct $W$.

$W$ is constructed by connecting two (hollow) cylinders by drilling a hole in the two cylinders and connecting them along the hole.

So you get a space $W = X \cup Y$ of the form

$\quad$$\quad$  $\quad$ [image]

Where the spaces $X$ and $Y$ are essentially identical

$\quad$$\quad$  $\quad$ [image]

And $W$ is obtained by gluing $X$ and $Y$ so that their intersection is a circle:

$\quad$ $\quad$ $\quad$ [image]

---

---

I do not want to use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Instead, I want to use Euler characteristics $\chi(W)$ and recover $\beta_i$ from

$$\chi(W) = \beta_0(W)- \beta_1(W)+\beta_2(W)$$

I notice that $\beta_0(W)=1$ ($W$ has one connected component) and $\beta_2(W) = 0$ (no enclosed void in $W$). Next, I want to use additivity of the Euler characteristic:

$$
\chi(X\cup Y) = \chi(X) + \chi(Y) - \chi(X \cap Y)
$$

Using the fact that $X\cap Y$ is a circle so its Euler characteristic is zero.

---

Because $X$ and $Y$ are identical, it is enough to compute $\chi(X)$. Now, the space $X$ is equivalent to a cylinder with an open disk removed. I know that the Euler characteristic of a cylinder is zero. Consequently, removing a disk from a cylinder will yield a space whose Euler characteristic is $-1$, yielding $\chi(X) = \chi(Y) = -1$.

Overall, I obtain

$$
\chi(X\cup Y) = - 1 + -1  - 0 = -2,
$$

yielding 
$$
-2 = \chi(X\cup Y) =   \chi(W)  = \beta_0(W) - \beta_1(W) + \beta_2(W) = 1 - \beta_1(W) + 0,
$$

it follows that $\beta_1(W) = 3$.

---

Intuitively I would expect to have a higher $\beta_1$ for $W$. Did I miss something or this calculation is correct? Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks reasonable to me.  Another way to think about it is that $W$ is homotopic to a sphere with four holes punched in it.  A loop around each hole is a generator of $H_1(W)$, but the sum of all of those loops is homologous to a loop around all the holes, and that's contractible by going around the other end of the sphere.  So the sum of all four generators is zero in homology.

Comment: Would it also be correct to say that adding three loops gives the forth loop? So we have four holes but only three "independent" loops?

Comment: Yes! Algebraically that's the same thing, and you can see why topologically too.